# Hexadecimal to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, nsnumber

I'm having issues with converting a hexadecimal number to an `NSNumber`. I tried a ton of things, but I can't seem to work it out.

With something like the following, how can I get an `NSNumber`?

```
Byte test[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x7A}; // Expected result is 7546
NSData * testData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&test length:4];
// NSNumber = ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has the following methods

```
- (BOOL)scanHexFloat:(float *)result
- (BOOL)scanHexDouble:(double *)result
- (BOOL)scanHexLongLong:(unsigned long long *)result
- (BOOL)scanHexInt:(unsigned *)intValue
```

so you can scan a hex NSString representation. Discussion for the last one:

> The hexadecimal integer representation may optionally be preceded by
>   0x or 0X. Skips past excess digits in the case of overflow, so the
>   receiver’s position is past the entire hexadecimal representation.
>   Invoke this method with NULL as intValue to simply scan past a
>   hexadecimal integer representation.

Comment: So I ended adding a category to NSData to get a hex representation, and your solution worked flawlessly. Thanks for the help!